# Bootstrap not responsive when browser is resized or on different device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I build a simple bootstrap website and I am having a problem getting it to be responsive when the browser is resized or viewed on a different device. I've added the size for the different sizes like "lg, sm, md , xs" etc but it is still not working. One of the problems is that I have 4 videos divs that seem to be slightly longer in width than my video on top. 
[Here is am image of that problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IHfC.png)

[Here is an snippet of the website when the browser is resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ubNT.png)

What is suppose to happen when browser is resized is that the videos are suppose to stay aligned with the bottom of the device/browser and for the top video to fill in the rest. And if you go to an xs size, I want the videos to line up vertically and I have it set to where the left column disappears. So pretty much I want no white spaces when resizing and keep as same as when it is in large view but until they go to a xs size. Here is a link to my code
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrVmVb

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <nav class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                    <h1>test</h1><hr />

                </div>
                <!--sticky footer-->
                <footer class="footer">
                    <div>
                        <p align="center">
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a id="lang_selected"><b>English</b></a> | <a href="es/irma.html">Español</a>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="row no-gutter">

        <main role="main" class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 ml-sm-auto">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls">
                    <source id="source_video" src="" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutter">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="firstVideo()">
                                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <p id="testText">this is sometext</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="secondVideo()">
                                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="thirdVideo()">
                                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="well">
                    <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item" controls="controls" onclick="fourthVideo()">
                            <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove padding-left:0;

.no-gutter > [class*='col-']{

```
padding-right:0;

padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0;
```

}